# boost::geometry::simplify has undocumented requirements/bad implementation or am i doing it wrong

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits, boost-geometry

I registered a custom linestring type, it fulfills the random access range concept. The tag is registered too.

So i tried using `boost::geometry::simplify` on it.

Then i found out `boost::geometry::traits::clear,resize,push_back<MyLineStringType>` needs to implemented if the type doesn't have these operations with same names.

Afaik not documented as requirements, but okay, was able to implement it for my type.

Then the ugly thing:

`simplify` doesn't use the `traits::push_back` internally but `std::back_inserter`.
So it's basicly impossible to use a custom type without a member push_back.

Or am i allowed to spezialize the `back_inserter` inside the stl namespace?

Is there any reason why simplify uses the `back_inserter` instead of the `traits::push_back` which seems to meant for this case? To me this looks like bad design.

Edit: I cannot change the interface of my linestring.

Edit2: code fragments from simplify using std::back_inserter instead of boost::geometry::traits<>::push_back

```
struct simplify_copy
{
    template <typename Range, typename Strategy, typename Distance>
    static inline void apply(Range const& range, Range& out,
                             Distance const& , Strategy const& )
    {
        std::copy
            (
                boost::begin(range), boost::end(range), std::back_inserter(out)
            );
    }
};


template<std::size_t Minimum>
struct simplify_range
{
    template <typename Range, typename Strategy, typename Distance>
    static inline void apply(Range const& range, Range& out,
                    Distance const& max_distance, Strategy const& strategy)
    {
        /*  ...  */
        if (boost::size(range) <= int(Minimum) || max_distance < 0.0)
        {
            /* ... */
        }
        else
        {
            simplify_range_insert::apply
                (
                    range, std::back_inserter(out), max_distance, strategy
                );
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to provide `push_back` for your container/traits/whatever. `std::back_inserter` returns `std::back_insert_iterator`. The latter is specified by the standard to use `push_back` in its `operator==`. This is its only purpose in life. So it is safe to say that `simplify` uses `push_back` indirectly (but fairly transparently). BTW there's no `stl::`.

Comment: Well i cannot modify my Linestring type. It has a push_back operation which is named differently.

"So it is safe to say that simplify uses push_back indirectly" yeah but it SHOULD use traits::push_back but just uses MyLineStringType::push_back through std::back_inserter.

"You need to provide push_back for your container/traits/whatever"
This is the important point, and not a "whatever". I can define proper traits, but not change the interface of my linestring type.

Comment: Since boost uses its own back_inserter and no std::back_inserter, you can specialize it.

Comment: Do you have any code? We can't possibly judge whether you're doing it wrong. We can't even check whether `std::back_inserter` is used at all, or unconditionally.

Comment: Inserted the code fragements of boost::simplify which seem to ignore the requirements stated in the documentation.

Comment: This was a bug, it should be fixed in Boost 1.61. so you could modify your copy of Boost (I don't know which version you're using) or use the latest version.